# Jetty server for Windows

Tags: windows, jetty

Can the Jetty server run on Windows-based environments. If there is a Windows installable, can someone please point me to it?

Answer (score 30):

I found [a good tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20120809013424/http://sos.blog-city.com/installationjetty.htm) and the [quick start documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quick-start-getting-started.html) on the installation of Jetty in a windows environment.  It's not simply an installer, but you merely unzip the files into a folder and run the command:

`java -jar start.jar`

in the folder where you unzipped it to start the server.

Answer (score 5):

[Jetty downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html)

Reference: [Jetty Quick Start](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quick-start.html)

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

1 – Downloading

You can download Jetty from two sources: Eclipse or Codehaus.

```
http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/downloads.php
```

2 - Simply uncompress the file to a directory.

3 – Running Jetty

Open a terminal.
Go to the Jetty installation directory.
Enter the following command:

```
$ java -jar start.jar
```

Now open a browser and go to localhost to check if Jetty was installed sucessfully:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have jar file created by maven and has all the dependencies you will require following command.

```
java -jar XXX.SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own XML based configuration file and pass it along with the startup command:

```
java -jar start.jar /path/to/jetty.xml
```

For example, if you want to use something else than 8080, then just put **jetty.port** inside the **jetty.xml**:

```
<Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="9090" /></Set>
```

Or those who are impatient, can just start up their instance with:

```
java -jar start.jar --module=http jetty.port=9090
```

If you'r using Jetty version 9.x. You need to go to `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini` file and edit this setting **jetty.http.port**.

```
jetty.http.port=9090
```